# Rails redirect_to with string url - take all parameters from request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, redirect, parameters

I want to redirect using the string form:

```
redirect_to "#{Settings.mobile_host}/main.html##{u_app.token}"
```

But I want to pass all parameters from the request (`request.parameters`). can't find the answer in the Rails docs.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You shouldn't really be using your initial `params` in the page you redirect to, your code will become very cryptic. Generally if it isn't in the Rails docs then you probably aren't meant to do it!